# Protocol doesn't work in collectionView Item

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with a few items in a TableView Cell and each item should push to the next ViewController, the problem is that I can't use the push() function from the collectionView and tableView Cell, so I created a Protocol which provokes the push function from the Main ViewController when I use to click on a collectionView item.

This is the Protocol:

```
protocol PushToAgents {
    
    func pushToAgents()
}
```

This is the Main Vc where I implement the function from the Protocol:

```
class MoreViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, PushToAgents, PushToBank, PushToCredit, PushToNewInserate {
    
    //MARK: - Protocol Functions
    
    func pushToAgents() {
        present(AgentsVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And this is the CollectionView:

```
class FeatureCollectionCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var agentsDelegate: PushToAgents?
    var bankDelegate: PushToBank?
    var creditDelegate: PushToCredit?
    var newInserateDelegate: PushToNewInserate?
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            agentsDelegate?.pushToAgents()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.bankDelegate?.pushToBank()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            self.creditDelegate?.pushToCredit()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            self.newInserateDelegate?.pushToNewInserate()
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it does nothing, can someone help and tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Did you initial your properties of delegate?

Comment: FeatureCollectionCell Is both a table cell and a collection view delegate and data source?

Comment: @YuriiPetrov what do you mean?

Comment: @jnpdx Yes it is a tableView Cell with a CollectionView on it!

Comment: Please add cellForRow method of table view

Comment: Oh thank you guys I forgot to initialize the delegates in the tableView cellForRow Method, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The view hierarchy should be like

```
ViewController -> TableView -> TableViewCell -> CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell
```

So the data passing should be reversed.

```
ViewController <- TableView <- TableViewCell <- CollectionView <- CollectionViewCell
```

You need to set the table view cell as the delegate of the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol PushToAgents:class {
    func collectionView(collectioncell:CustomCollectionViewCell?, didTap TableCell:CustomTableViewCell)
}
```

// Table Cell Configure

```
weak var cellDelegate:PushToAgents? 

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell
        self.cellDelegate?.collectionView(collectioncell: cell, didTap: self)
    }
```

// Inside cellForRow

```
cell?.cellDelegate = self
```

// ViewController Configure

```
extension ViewController:PushToAgents {
    func collectionView(collectioncell: CustomCollectionViewCell?, didTap TableCell: CustomTableViewCell) {

    }
}
```